# http status always showing as 404

Tags: javascript

I have a http status trying to detect if the website is a 404 or another error page so I can do some fancy stuff to show error messages. My code looks like this. Not quite sure why it always comes back as a 404 error even when the page is fine. Any ideas?

```
var data = 'https://www.google.com/';
   function UrlExists(data) {
      var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      http.open('HEAD', data, false);
      http.send();
     if (data === '' || data === null || http.status === 404 || http.status === 500|| http.status === 400){
         console.log(http.status)
         $('iframe').hide();
         $('.errorDiv').show();
       } else {
               $('iframe').show();
               $('.errorDiv').hide();
               console.log(data)
               viewModel.Src(data);
               model.set('Src', data);
        }
      }
     UrlExists(data)
```

Comment: You're calling it with nothing?

Comment: you dont pass anything into your function.  Based on your implementation, you need to pass in a URL to your `UrlExists` function

Comment: You need to wait for the `send()` to complete - see [MDN send example](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send#Example)

Comment: @StephenP What do you mean wait? I have never used anything like this before so I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better for all if you done some background reading before posting a question. There are plenty of resources about AJAX

Comment: @EdHeal I have done two days of reading about this and am on a deadline. I am doing something very specific and came to this website because I needed some help. Thought that was what this was for, sorry for not knowing everything about everything.

Comment: Perhaps use this pattern http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_header as a starting point tp get the status

Comment: @EdHeal I've looked at that example, but I'm not seeing where you can pass in a Url, it seems to be only be pulling the page it is on.

Comment: The line `xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);` has the URL. It has to be one the same domain as the web page that is running the JS. Otherwise you need CORS (i.e. the other domains permission).

Comment: @zaz - What Ed is referring to, [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) is Cross Origin Resource Sharing - your script will not be allowed to do the HEAD request you are attempting due to security restrictions in browsers. What I mean about wait is, your `.send()` call sends the HEAD request and the call returns _immediately_, before a response is received. You attach callbacks for onload, onerror, etc which get called when the actual HTTP send/receive is finished (or fails). See the MDN I linked to earlier, for "Events" under "SEE ALSO" in the left nav.